# Jump i5-10600K to i9-11900KF

Tags: windows-10, drivers, cpu, bios, gpu

**System Information**

- OS Name   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro for Workstations
- Version   10.0.19045 Build 19045
- System Manufacturer   ASUS
- Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10600K CPU @ 4.10GHz, 4101 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)
- BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends Inc. 2602, 2022-01-20
- SMBIOS Version    3.2
- Embedded Controller Version   255.255
- BIOS Mode UEFI
- BaseBoard Manufacturer    ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
- BaseBoard Product TUF GAMING Z490-PLUS (WI-FI)
- BaseBoard Version Rev 1.xx
- Platform Role Desktop
- Secure Boot State Off
- PCR7 Configuration    Elevation Required to View
- Windows Directory C:\Windows
- System Directory  C:\Windows\system32
- Boot Device   \Device\HarddiskVolume3
- Locale    United States
- Hardware Abstraction Layer    Version = "10.0.19041.2728"
- Time Zone Eastern Daylight Time
- Installed Physical Memory (RAM)   32.0 GB
- Total Physical Memory 31.9 GB
- Available Physical Memory 26.0 GB
- Total Virtual Memory  36.9 GB
- Available Virtual Memory  28.6 GB
- Page File Space   5.00 GB
- Page File C:\pagefile.sys
- Kernel DMA Protection Off
- Virtualization-based security Not enabled
- Device Encryption Support Elevation Required to View
- Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions  Yes
- Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions Yes
- Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware  No
- Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection   Yes

**GPU**

- Name  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070
- PNP Device ID PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_2786&SUBSYS_51371462&REV_A1\4&38AB2860&0&0008
- Adapter Type  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070, NVIDIA compatible
- Adapter Description   NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070
- Adapter RAM   (1,048,576) bytes
- Installed Drivers C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvmdig.inf_amd64_d24a95fa21389db6\nvldumdx.dll,C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvmdig.inf_amd64_d24a95fa21389db6\nvldumdx.dll,C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvmdig.inf_amd64_d24a95fa21389db6\nvldumdx.dll,C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvmdig.inf_amd64_d24a95fa21389db6\nvldumdx.dll
- Driver Version    31.0.15.3598
- INF File  oem34.inf (Section033 section)
- Color Planes  Not Available
- Color Table Entries   4294967296
- Resolution    1920 x 1080 x 279 hertz
- Bits/Pixel    32
- Memory Address    0x91000000-0x920FFFFF
- Memory Address    0x0000-0x11FFFFFF
- Memory Address    0x10000000-0x11FFFFFF
- I/O Port  0x00003000-0x00003FFF
- IRQ Channel   IRQ 16
- Driver    C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERSTORE\FILEREPOSITORY\NVMDIG.INF_AMD64_D24A95FA21389DB6\NVLDDMKM.SYS (31.0.15.3598, 56.26 MB (58,992,640 bytes), 2023-05-31 3:48 PM)

https://ca.pcpartpicker.com/b/6Wykcf
my pc part picker build, instead of 3070 i have a 4070.

**Context**

I wanted to upgrade my cpu, by buying the biggest processor that my mobo can support, the i9-11900. So I bought the i9-11900KF. Actually I have i5-10600K. Bios setting are xmp profile enable, and igpu desactivated, so the graphic card in cpu is disabled for my i5-10600K. my cpu run at 4.8 ghz. my ram is at 3600mhz

So I installed the new cpu. the bios detected it. I enabled xmp profile to get my ram run at 3600mghz. the new cpu run between 5 ghz and 5.3 ghz because i let the bios decide.

**Problem**

The problem is that instead of having a fps gain in my games, I get 75% fps drop.

Fortnite 350fps to 130fps
Valorant 500fps to 80 fps
Jedi     100fps to 5 fps.

I tried multiple settings. I even format my disk, and installed a fresh copy of windows 10.

have a day of frustration. I reinstalled my i5-10600k. and all my FPS get back to normal.

Comment: Is your cooling adequate? Can the PSU provide enough power for this CPU?

Comment: Based on the documentation, your motherboard didn't even support your new processor, until firmware revision 2207 and you certainly don't have that revision of the firmware installed

Comment: My cooler is Lian Li GALAHAD AIO 360 RGB 69.17 CFM Liquid CPU Cooler. My PSU is Corsair RM650 (2019) 650 W 80+ Gold Certified Fully Modular ATX Power Supply.

Comment: Wow I have the BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends Inc. 2602, 2022-01-20
. So this cpu is not compatible with that version.

Comment: pc part picker tell me that it will work with my mobo if i install 2207 bios version. so i'm gonna buy a i9-10900k instead.